# how to find the limit of $\lim_{x \to0}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to find the limit of $$\lim_{x \to0}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2}\,?$$
I tried L'Hospital's rule, but it didn't work well.

Can I have some assistance? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x+1}.$$ You will get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x+1}}$$ and the limit is $$\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since, near $0$,$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=1+\frac x2+\frac{3x^2}8+O(x^3)$$and$$\sqrt{x+1}=1+\frac x2-\frac{x^2}8+O(x^3),$$then$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2}=\frac38-\left(-\frac18\right)=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 1):

why apply l hopital when you can rationlaise..

$$\lim_{x \to0}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2}$$

and you will get the following

$$\lim_{x \to0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x+1}}$$

put $ x =0 $ you will get  $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Could you please explain how your answer is different from Dr Sonnhard's answer?

Comment: i was wring the the answer and decorating it with latex...then when posted it...and aldready saw that someone posted the same solution

Comment: That's fine, just checking.

Comment: should i remove it?

Comment: You can try adding another method to your answer, but only if you can think of anything.

Comment: after posting ..i was thinking of approaching with another solution...and was quite impressed with jose carlos solution